# Validation fails with "no matching profiles found... "

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Since the update to Xcode 6, I am having problems with validation of my app: see screenshot.

I have no idea, what this means, and what I can do...

Note: I do have valid profiles in Xcode and in the Dev Portal, and I can run the app from Xcode.

[image]

Please advice

Answer (score 1):

It means that either you have no valid provisioning profiles installed or you haven't selected the correct ones in your target's build settings.

Go to your target's build settings and look at Code Signing and its Provisioning Profiles fields.
Select the correct provisioning profiles for your schemas and after you do that look at Code Signing Identities fields and make sure that the identities for each schema match the provisioning profiles.

[image]

Comment: Right, this is how it should work. I know that. But since I upgrade to Xcode 6, it does not work like that anymore... I deleted all my profiles, generated new ones, followed your advice (BTW, that's how I always did it before), but to no avail!

Comment: Did you refreshed your account in Xcode's preferences pane? In your Developer Portal are all your Certificates and Provisioning Profiles Valid? Also check your app's bundle identifier in Xcode and compare it to your Provisioning Profiles and App ID.

Comment: Hmm.. that's very odd... Did you try to clean up your project?

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing this issue too - everything was working fine pre xcode 6.

EDIT - In my case, under code signing, the selection was set to distribution.  I clicked into this and saw I had two distribution options (one for a developer account and one for enterprise).  Explicity setting the correct one here solved the issue.  It seems xcode 6 introduces a change to the automatic selection behaviour.  Hope that helps!

Comment: This should be post as comment not an answer.

Comment: Sorry Manhatan, realised that after I posted.  Although have a plausible answer now, have edited to explain how I resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out for the developer accounts in your Xcode preferences.

If you are a member of multiple teams then choose the correct team from there and if one of the account's developer info has been changed then remove that account from your Xcode preferences.

Try to remove the additional developer accounts of previous clients if there. I had this.

Also pressing the cancel button and doing it again by quitting Xcode or choosing Import Developer Profile from the above screenshot can help you.

In my case it worked for me.

Hope it helps you too.